# Filename encoding issue when building through TeamCity but not if logged into the machine and building manually

Tags: .net, msbuild, teamcity, msbuild-task

I have an issue when compiling a project using TeamCity.
If I log onto the machine and manually run the build script using msbuild it compiles fine, all custom build tasks compile and run as intended, tests compile and run and the script that creates the installer also runs fine.

But once I run the same build script using the same msbuild version from TeamCity I get encoding issues.

In one place I have a build task that converts **docx** files to **pdf**. It takes a list of documents to convert and in one place one of these names contain german characters. This turn up as a question mark on a black diamond in TeamCity logs, the build task reports it can't find that file and the build fails.

I have tried converting all file encoding of the msbuild scripts to utf-8 and for good measure added

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

to each build script. The exact same error occurs anyway.

I have tried using the **msbuild** build step within TeamCity and also the **command line** build step and manually calling the same msbuild I use when logging in to the machine and building manually. All attempts result in the exact same error.

Is there some setting within TeamCity itself I have to change to avoid this or what could be causing it?

Versions used:

- TeamCity 2018.2.2 (build 61245)
- Msbuild (Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild). So Build Engine 4.7.2046.0 and .NET Framework version 4.0.30319.42000
- Build Server OS Windows Server 2012 R2
- Build Agent os Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Can you just rename the file that has German characters?

Comment: @CJohnson: I CAN, but it would mask the actual issue and it would make us end up with documents not named correctly since they are named in the different languages so non-english speakers have no issues finding them.

Comment: Quite possible that teamcity is running under a different user (service) and that it has different default encoding set.

Comment: @inquisitive: At first it was running as the SYSTEM account. But I actually changed it to the same account I do the manual tests with in order to eliminate variables. But good call otherwise because the SYSTEM account did present a few issues.